# If i install ubuntu, do i need to install specific drivers?

Tags: drivers, sound

Recently i got a very old pentium 4 windows machine and it didn't have any sound drivers. I tried looking for them and after i found them i couldn't install them. I was thinking of moving to ubuntu  but i'm not sure whether i will need to install the sound drivers on it too? If i have to install drivers, i would rather keep windows because finding drivers for such an old machine will be hard.

Comment: What type of sound card do you need? And you can always just burn an Ubuntu CD and try Ubuntu right from the CD and test all the hardware.

Comment: Check the hardware system requirements for Ubuntu before you try it.

Comment: My old computer's sound card needs a driver and sound does not work without driver. But it works out of the box in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot ubuntu from cd without installing and see if everything needed is working.
Usually that's a pretty good hint to what hardware works out of the box.

There's a comprehensive howto and "whatis" on the help pages:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD